# Lightweight server with amd64 architecture

Tags: linux, server, quiet-computing, processor-architecture

I am looking for a quiet server with low power consumption. I am interested in running Ubuntu server with Livepatch in such a server, so that is why it has that amd64 architecture requirement. A great feature would be battery backup in case of power outage; at least it should be able to restart automatically when power is available again (if possible battery runs out).